# getting at namespace data when Parsing Xml on Python 2.6.6 with ElementTree 1.2.6

Tags: python, elementtree

I have some xml that I need to parse, which is supplied in the following format:

```
<Pres xmlns:abset="titan:arm:params:xml:ns:keyprov:abset">
<Set>
    <Key>
        <Id>c91e3882-e6f3-41f9-af52-3473a2c4615a</Id>
        <abset:Data>
            <abset:Tag>
                <abset:Value>i need this</abset:Value>
            </abset:Tag>
        </abset:Data>
    </Key>
</Set>
</Pres>
```

With Python 2.7, I can get at the abset:Value with the following:

```
xmlstr          = '...'
root            = ElementTree.fromstring(xmlstr)

ns              = {'abset' : 'titan:arm:params:xml:ns:abset'}

keyElement      = root.find("./Set/Key")
value           = keyElement.find("./abset:Data/abset:Tag/abset:Value", ns).text
```

But in python 2.6, the find command doesn't support the ns argument.

I've tried 
    ValElement = root.find("./Set/Key/abset:Data/abset:Tag/abset:Value")
    value = ValElement.text

But the error I get is

```
 keyelement      = root.find("./Set/Key/abset:Data/abset:Tag/abset:Value")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 330, in find
    return ElementPath.find(self, path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 186, in find
    return _compile(path).find(element)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 176, in _compile
    p = Path(path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 93, in __init__
    "expected path separator (%s)" % (op or tag)
SyntaxError: expected path separator (:)
```

How can I access these elements in python 2.6.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to specify the namespace in full, so instead of `root.find("./Set/Key/abset:Data/abset:Tag/abset:Value")` you should use `root.find("./Set/Key/{titan:arm:params:xml:ns}Data/{titan:arm:params:xml:ns}Tag/{titan:arm:params:xml:ns}Value")`